# Initialised non-reactive members in Typescript Vue class

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Using [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) you can define a Vue component as a Typescript class like this:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Component from "vue-class-component"

@Component({})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  public foo: number = 123;
  public bar: string = "123";
}
```

All member variables become reactive. Vue traverses the object and replaces all fields with getters that notify Vue when they are set. It does this deeply - i.e. it recurses into sub-objects.

Often I want to store some data in the class that *isn't* reactive, because adding reactivity is pretty slow.

The only way to do that that I know of is to make the field undefined:

```
@Component({})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  public foo?: number;
  public bar?: string;
}
```

But that kind of sucks, because then you have to check for `undefined` everywhere, or use `public foo!: number` and risk type errors. And the field isn't initialised!

Is there a way to have an initialised field that isn't reactive?

Answer (score 0):

The only method I know of to initialise a field is by making it read-only:

```
get foo(): string { return 'hello' };
```

You could also assign to properties during the created lifecycle hook, this is often the approach that I take:

```
foo: ClassName;

created(){
    this.foo = new ClassName();
};
```

However, if you wish to have a number of assignable properties that can be initialised (that are non-reactive) then it's likely more appropriate to use a separate class that does not extend `Vue`.

I often do this if I require more complex objects that are not concerned with the view and therefore don't need to be reactive.